# Rewrite and redirect a url with variables and google tag manager

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am using a booking system on my website. The form gets proccess on a second page because I need a custom url to be written using the variables from the form. The form is being hosted in the header.php page of a wordpress website. Once they click submit, they are taken to a page with the following code:

```html
$TheLink = 'https://demo.reztrip.com/search?' . '&arrival_date=' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['date'])) . '&departure_date=' . date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['date'] . " + {$_GET['nights']} days"));
   header( "Location: $TheLink" ) ;
```

The client is requesting that the google analytics get carried over to the redirect.

I understand I cannot just add them to this second booking page because it his a redirect and no other code will be processed.

I have looked into meta redirects or js redirects but I get lost at combining my php to rewrite the url and the js to redirect.

Is there a simpler way to achieve the redirect with the rewritten url with the google tags getting carried over?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use Google Tag Manager for data collection and not for setting redirects.  If you need to implement Google Analytics on destination page, than try to add GTM code to destination page.

If you use redirect for something like building goal funnels in Google Analytics, than you can try to use virtual page views instead.